# Отрисовка движущихся объектов в браузере

Tags: анимация, графика, javascript, разработка-игр, css

Всегда интересовало - как разработчики браузерных игр вроде Тюряги из Вконтакте рисуют движения персонажей? Просто чередуют картинки или программно двигают фигуры?

Comment: Программно, конечно. По кадрам только мультики в блокнотах рисуются.

Comment: Если анимация сделана на javascript, то каждый кадр анимации это полная перерисовка объекта, но, думаю, в таких играх анимация это flash.

Comment: А как примерно выглядит код прорисовки объекта?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[@Alex9](/users/12309/alex9), если вы хотите написать игру, то читайте книги по созданию компьютерных игр. На форуме вы не получите фундаментальных знаний.

Если вы хотите сделать копию Тюряги и самому зарабатывать деньги на продаже всяких дополнений, то наймите программистов, художников, маркетологов, сценаристов, писателей, системных администраторов и обслуживающий персонал. За несколько месяцев упорной работы у вас получится копия. Останется только договориться об отчислениях с mail.ru, вложить деньги в рекламу и собрать игроков, которые смогут по рублю восстанавливать ваши затраты. Если игрокам понравится, то при хорошем раскладе через некоторое время вы окупите свои вложения.

Если вам просто интересно, то пишут примерно такой код:

```
//создаем круг диаметром 20px, расположенный по координатам 100,100
create_cicrcle(100px,100px,20px);

//смещаем круг в координаты 20,50 и увеличивает радиус до 40px.    
move_circle(20px,50px,40px);
```

Для получения более точных ответов, старайтесь задавать более точные вопросы.

Comment: В программе Blender